# ruby: difference between (0..) and (0...)

Tags: ruby, range

As far as I can tell `(0..)` and `(0...)` do and are the same thing, however if you look at [the range documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Range.html) it says that

> - `(1..)` and `(1...)` are not equal, although technically representing the same sequence.

So I kept looking everywhere and I couldn't find what the difference is.

What differentiates the two ranges above?

Comment: I guess one is _up to and including_ infinity while the other _is up to and **not** including_ infinity? Which is meaningless on a practical basis, but perhaps makes a difference just because of how Ruby stores a range's attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From RubyDocs:

> **rng == obj → true or false**
>
> Returns true only if obj is a `Range`, has equivalent begin and end items (by comparing them with ==), and has the same `exclude_end?` setting as the range.

So:

```rb
(1..).exclude_end?
=> false

(1...).exclude_end?
=> true

(1..) == (1...)
=> false
```

So, a practically meaningless distinction, as @max says, but technically Ruby considers them to be different since one is technically `infinity - 1`.